# Use Load runner web_reg_save_param_regexp save the number after tvNode_R- from a block of html code

Tags: regex, loadrunner

I use the regular expression attached but it works without adding the highlighted "ORG_40365", once I added "ORG_40365" it does not work.
However, I need to specify the occurrence related to specific node and need to add "ORG_40365" at the end. Otherwise will return other value unexpected.
[Please click here to see the web_reg_save_param_regexp used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgLCE.jpg)

I cannot copy the code here as it does not allow me to save with error.

[image: Code screenshot]

I have the above string and want to save `9704` after `tvNode_R-`. However, the regular expression does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please delete this screen shoot and add codes to question with text format

Comment: have you considered just the use of " web_reg_save_param("Mycapture","LB=tvNode_R-","RB=\" class","ORD=1",LAST);" ?

Comment: web_reg_save_param will not save unqiue one based on the last ORG value as there are multiple occurrences. In addition, the boundary in between the html code such as style/color can change.

Comment: web_reg_save_param("foo","LB=<td class=\"dxtIHEC\"></td></tr><tr id=\"",RB=\" class=", "ORD=1",LAST);   Post process foo to find the location of the hyphen and then use an offset to save to a new string, lr_save_string("destination_variable",  &lr_eval_string("{foo}")[34] );

Comment: As mentioned, LB=<td class=\"dxtIHEC\"></td></tr><tr id=\"",RB=\" class=", is not unique, even the whole block of html code is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

## Foreward

Pattern Matching HTML can be rather difficult so it's generally recommended to use an HTML parsing tool.

Also I manually transcribed your photo of text. I recommend either replacing the photo with real text or inserting real text in addition to the photo.

## Description

`<tr(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|=(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))*?\sclass=['"]dxtlNode)(?=(?:[^>=]|=(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))*?\sid=['"][^"]*tvNode_R-([0-9]{4}))(?:[^>=]|=(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"\s]*))*\s?\/?>`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- find `tr` tags
- require the `tr` tag to have an class `dxtlNode`
- require the `tr` tag to have an id with `tvNode_R-` followed by 4 digits
- Captures the 4 digits identified above into Capture Group 1
- Capture the entire opening `tr` tag into Capture Group 0
- Avoids some difficult edge cases which makes pattern matching in HTML difficult

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/gK5dM0/1

**Sample text**

```
<td class="dxtlHSEC"></td></tr><tr id="m_m_splitMaster_P_TC_p_n_tvNode_R-9704" 
class="dxtlNode" oncontextmenup="return aspxTLMenu(&#39;m_m_splitMaster_P_TC_p_n_tvNode&#39;,&#39;Node&#39;,&#39;;9704&#39;,event)">
<span class="btxt">ORG_40365</span></td><td class="dstlHSEC"></td></tr>
```

**Sample Matches**

```
Capture Group 0.    [31-211]  `<tr id="m_m_splitMaster_P_TC_p_n_tvNode_R-9704" class="dxtlNode" oncontextmenup="return aspxTLMenu(&#39;m_m_splitMaster_P_TC_p_n_tvNode&#39;,&#39;Node&#39;,&#39;;9704&#39;,event)">`
Capture Group 1.    [73-77]   `9704`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <tr                      '<tr'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace
                                 (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or
                                 more times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    class=                   'class='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]                     any character of: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dxtlNode                 'dxtlNode'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace
                                 (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or
                                 more times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    id=                      'id='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]                     any character of: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    tvNode_R-                'tvNode_R-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                               whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The user is engaged in performance test with the tool LoadRunner so the parsing needs to be in context with the execution of a virtual user, capturing a value sent back from the server for reuse later in the same test.  Using an external HTML parsing tool manually is not going to be possible in this context

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I can add the attachment. Cannot use web_reg_save_param as there are multiple occurrences for the boundary, need to match certain pattern.

Comment: Consider the use of an ordinal to pick up the appropriate nth instance